# View controller slide down animation IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

I'm new to iOS development and I can't quite understand the solutions that are out there. Not sure if they apply to me either.

I currently have a button that opens the next view controller in a slide up (default) animation.

In that view controller I have a back button. I would like to slide the current view controller down to present the previous view controller that is still there.

However, my back button appears to slide up a new view controller. Is there a simple way to slide down the current VC to display the previous? Or must I make a custom animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presenting a view controller modally (slide up).  The same view controller that does the presentation can also call [`dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) to dismiss it.  It will handle all animations for you.

You just need to make sure to wire up your 'back button' correctly.  It sounds like at the moment it's hooked up to keep presenting new controllers.

Edit - In Objective C:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Thanks. Dismiss was a keyword that was missing in my attempts to find a solution. I solved it by adding this line of code!

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Yes, my example was in Swift.  Sorry I overlooked the Objective C tag in your question.  Glad you got it though.